# Select first row in each GROUP BY group with Postgres aggregate functions?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two tables: `user` to keep track of user info and `users_classes` to keep track of relations between users and classes (classes are in a separate table). I want to join the tables and return the user's info along with an array of the classes they're in. Is there an efficient way to do so?

Table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE users (
  id        BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  username  VARCHAR(255) UNIQUE,
  email     VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL UNIQUE
)

CREATE TABLE users_classes (
  user_id   BIGINT REFERENCES users(id),
  class_id  BIGINT REFERENCES classes(id),
  PRIMARY KEY(user_id, class_id)
)
```

My attempt:

```
SELECT
  u.id,
  FIRST(u.username) AS username,
  FIRST(u.email) AS email,
  array_agg(c.class_id) AS classes
FROM users_classes AS c
JOIN users AS u
ON c.user_id = u.id
GROUP BY u.id;
```

I think this could work (after implementing FIRST()), but is there a more standard way to do it?

Comment: Kindly provide sample data, the result that you are getting and your expected result.

Comment: the way you do it is very much standard. you aggregate column values into array grouping by other column. what looks not standard?..

Comment: @VaoTsun I'm just surprised that there is no FIRST() function built into Postgres natively, even though they have a [page on their wiki](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/First/last_(aggregate))

Comment: that's just en example on how to create an aggregate function. the list of existing is here: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-aggregate.html

Comment: Oh I just meant that I was surprised that there was no function already that functioned like their FIRST() example, since I figured that what I'm trying to do is relatively common

Comment: I mean in your case just try putting `MIN` instead of `first`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just ad the columns to the `GROUP BY` clause like this:

```
SELECT
  u.id,
  u.username,
  u.email,
  array_agg(c.class_id) AS classes
FROM users_classes AS c
  JOIN users AS u
    ON c.user_id = u.id
GROUP BY u.id, u.username, u.email;
```

Answer (score 1):

Postgres requires you specify how to pick up rows projection in group, so you have to specify an aggregation function for each select projection.

You could use `mode()` to pick first/last row in the group. Here is the example based on your question:

```
SELECT
  mode() WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY u.id) as userId,
  mode() WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY u.username DESC) as username, -- pick last username
  mode() WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY u.email) as email,
  array_agg(c.class_id) AS classes
FROM users_classes AS c
JOIN users AS u
ON c.user_id = u.id
GROUP BY u.id;
```